# PHP FPDF - make cell fill entire width of PDF page

Tags: php, fpdf

I have this footer in my PFDF:

```
// Page footer
function Footer(){
    // Position at 1 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-10);

    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);

        
    $this->SetFillColor(0,179,186); // bg
    $this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);

    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C',true);
}
```

However this code does not fill the entire page. It leaves a blank space at the left and right. I've put this in red color on this drawing:

[image]

How can I fill the entire width?

Answer (score 0):

These are the page margins and the "w" parameter is documented accordingly:

> [...]If 0, the cell extends up to the right margin.

The previously called SetY() method is documented simliar:

> Sets the ordinate and optionally moves the current abscissa back to the left margin.[...]

So you may change the page margins in your footer method, or do something like:

```
$pdf->SetXY(0, -10);
// ...style and color
$this->Cell($this->GetPageWidth(), 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C', true);
```